# I need to connect 2 switches to a router, what's the difference between creating 2 subnets and creating 2 "normal networks" with their own net ip?

Tags: networking, ip, router, subnet

I'm really confused about subnets right now, basically I have two separate networks that I need to connect to the same router and I need to explain how they are connected together, IPs, et cetera but then I got a doubt:

[image: network diagram]

In this image I represented a router connected to two networks. What's the difference of giving them one of the 192.168.0.0 to 192.168.128.0 network ip each and using the main router IP to create two subnets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The top network in your image is incorrect because you have the same network on both sides of the router. You cannot configure overlapping networks on a router. Routers route *between* networks, not from a network back to the same network.

Both networks on the right side of the router are part of the network on the left side of the router. A host in the `192.168.5.0/24` network could not send anything to either of the other two networks. The host will compare the destination address to its own address and mask, and it will decide that the destination is on its own network, so it will not send the packets to the router. It will try to find the layer-2 address of the destination, and it will be unable to do so, then drop the traffic.

Comment: But why? Isn't 192.168.5.5/24 for example different than 192.168.5.64.5/26?

Comment: No, `192.168.5.64/26` is part of the `192.168.5.0/24` network. If you look at it in binary, as network devices do, then it is obvious. Trying to do IP manipulation using the dotted decimal notation, which is only for human readability, is foolish, and it leads to errors. See the excellent answer to [this question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/7106/8499).

Comment: What if I changed the `192.168.5.0/24` to `192.168.5.0/26` and the router ip from `192.168.5.1/24` to `192.168.5.1/26` would it work?

Comment: Yes, those would be separate networks with no overlap. The `192.168.5.0/26` network goes from `192.168.5.0` to `192.168.5.63`, the `192.168.5.64/26` goes from `192.168.5.64` to `192.168.5.127`, and the `192.168.5.128/26` network goes from `192.168.5.128` to `192.168.5.191`. The point of subnetting is that you are assigned a large block of addresses, and you subnet to divide the large block into smaller, individual networks. None of the networks from subnetting can overlap.

Answer (score 2):

Your 192.168.5.65/26 subnet is actually part of the same subnet as 192.168.5.0/24. An address might fit more snugly into the /26 subnet but since the first 24 bits are still the same (192.168.5) the device won't bother to check outside the local connection for that destination.

Only when the local subnet doesn't match an address will your devices try to communicate to the other side of the router, so basically you need the subnets on the right to not contain 192.168.5. for routing to work.

[This site](http://www.calculator.net/ip-subnet-calculator.html) can help show you what changes when you edit subnets and what addresses are valid in each.